# How can I make text behind an image before the image has loaded?

Tags: html

Often, I can see some text in an image's place before the image has been loaded. How can I do this myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the text in the image's `alt` attribute

```
<img src='images/image.png' alt='My Text' />
```

Comment: Just a note: the alt attribute is actually a *required* attribute and should *always* be present.

Comment: @animuson: You would imagine that more people would upvote my answer for mentioning that, and one person wouldn't revoke the upvote they originally put in.

Answer (score 3):

That's represented by the image's `alt` attribute (which, by the way, is required):

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="Alternate text for image">
```

And in case you're wondering, no equivalent exists for background images in CSS. There shouldn't be, anyway, since background images are purely presentational.

Comment: Just so that the code is properly validated by HTML validator, you should close the img tag. `<img src="image.jpg" alt="Alternate text for image" />`

Comment: @Virendra: It's not necessary in HTML as it already self-closes. You only need to add the slash when validating against XHTML — that rule is imposed by XML, not HTML.