# CSS/HTML - How do I get text to go behind an image inside a div

Tags: css, image, html, text

Basically what I want to do is make all text go behind an image within a div.

Something like this:

```
<div> 1 
     <img>
</div>
```

Comment: use http://jsfiddle.net for demo

Comment: Do you want the text to be seen behind the image? Do you want the text to disappear from view altogether?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background Image of a <div> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604859/background-image-of-a-div-element)

Comment: I want for it to be covered by the image, but for it to be there so if or when the image leaves it can be seen

Comment: @Xansy use jsfiddle.net and explain what you want?

Comment: what do you mean `when the image leaves`?

Comment: this may http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671482/how-can-i-make-text-behind-an-image-before-the-image-has-loaded?answertab=active#tab-top help you

Comment: Do you mean if image present on div tag then hide the text and display only image and if image not present then display the text?

Comment: If the image were to be removed fromt the div the text would be seen, if the image is in the div then the text wouldnt been seen.

Comment: If you mean that the image were to be deleted but its `<img>` left in place, use the image's alt text `alt=""` field.

Comment: Not what I meant... I meant for it to be removed from the div, meaning it would be `<div> 1 </div>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Css and position for CSS

```
.mydiv{
    position:relative
}
.mydiv img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

And For Html

```
<div class="mydiv">
Mytext
<img src="myimage"/>
</div>
```

Wish this can Help

Answer (score 0):

```
    .Back{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    Backgroud-image:url();
    }
   <div class="Back">
    Hellooooooooo
   <div>
```